# How to narrow to python class?

Tags: python, narrowing

How can I narrow a buffer to the python class at point?

`narrow-to-region` works but requires first selecting the class as a region, and it seems `python-mode` has moved on since this was written:

http://blogs.fluidinfo.com/terry/2011/01/28/py-narrow-to-class/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the cursor the the top of the class and use `narrow-to-defun`.  You can reach the top of the class by using `python-nav-backward-up-list`.

Answer (score 4):

With erikstokes' answer, I was able to write this, which uses python.el to narrow to the outermost scope regardless of where point is in the class:

```
(defun my/python-narrow-to-outer-scope ()
    (interactive)
    (save-excursion
        (python-nav-beginning-of-block)
        (let ((last-point nil))
            (while (or (null last-point) (/= (point) last-point))
                (setq last-point (point))
                (python-nav-backward-up-list)))
        (forward-line)
        (narrow-to-defun)))
```

Or more specifically narrowing to the 'nearest' opening class definition (nearest moving up the hierarchy of class/def nesting from point):

```
(defun my/py-statement-opens-base (regexp)
(let ((orig (point))
        erg)
    (save-excursion
    (back-to-indentation)
    (python-nav-forward-statement)
    (python-nav-backward-statement)
    (when (and
            (<= (line-beginning-position) orig)(looking-back "^[ \t]*" (line-beginning-position))(looking-at regexp))
        (setq erg (point))))
    (when (called-interactively-p 'any) (message "%s" erg))
    erg))

(defconst my/py-class-re "[ \t]*\\_<\\(class\\)\\_>[ \n\t]"
"Matches the beginning of a class definition. ")

(defun my/py-statement-opens-class-p ()
"Return `t' if the statement opens a functions or class definition, nil otherwise. "
    (my/py-statement-opens-base my/py-class-re))

(defun my/python-narrow-to-class ()
    (interactive)
    (save-excursion
        (python-nav-beginning-of-block)
        (while (not (my/py-statement-opens-class-p))
            (python-nav-backward-up-list))
        (forward-line)
        (narrow-to-defun)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   (defun py-narrow-to-class ()
      "Make text outside current class invisible. "
      (interactive)
      (save-excursion
        (let ((start (if (py--statement-opens-class-p)
                         (point)
                       (py-beginning-of-class))))
          (py-end-of-class)
          (narrow-to-region (point) start))))
```

Meanwhile narrowing of basic forms like this --or block, statement etc.-- is implemented in python-mode.el.

Comment: I think this depends on python-model.el as opposed to python.el.  I'm using the latter because it comes with emacs.